# Use XML file or DB

Tags: json, xml, database

For my simple App, i have a ftp server where i can store file (json or xml) or DB. Multiple clients could access that file or DB to read or write (DB or file would have only up to 100 entries). 
From one point of view, DB is more suited for having big amounts of entries, due to indexing. But from other point of view, i am not sure if there would be issue with xml or json file if multiple clients try to read or write at the same time from the same file? So i am thinking to use DB just to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a database for a few reasons:

- Databases are designed for exactly this scenario.
- If you ever need to work on a larger scale you won't need to change your code.
- You'll get to practice writing db code that will be useful in future, larger scale projects.
- There are some really good database technologies that will work well with what you need, for example MongoDB, MySQL, SQL Server. They all have great support, code examples and you'll be able to use Stack Overflow to ask questions about them.

Answer (score 0):

After googling, it seems that SQLite is the best choice. It is good approach for small DB, it is self-contained, allowing safe access from multiple processes or threads. Exactly what i needed.